# Accessing elements of a dynamic table

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, code-behind

Hello guys I have the following HTML code which generates rows with fields, each row has a few fields, for the row1 there is an input named "sku1", etc..:

The problem is that when the page loads, none of the inputs skuX exist yet, hence making it not possible to access from the code behind.

The code from the table HTML

```
<table class="table table-striped" style="margin:10px" runat="server" id="tablaSKU" data-row-prototype="&quot;&lt;tr&gt; &lt;th&gt;__id__&lt;/th&gt; &lt;th class=&quot;col-sm-2&quot; name=&quot;sku&quot;&gt; &lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; id=&quot;sku__id__&quot; class=&quot;form-control&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot;&gt; &lt;/th&gt; &lt;th class=&quot;col-sm-1&quot;&gt; &lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; id=&quot;precio__id__&quot; class=&quot;form-control&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot;&gt; &lt;/th&gt; &lt;th class=&quot;col-sm-3&quot;&gt; &lt;input type=&quot;text&quot; id=&quot;descripProd__id__&quot; class=&quot;form-control&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot;&gt; &lt;/th&gt; &lt;th class=&quot;col-sm-2&quot;&gt; &lt;input type=&quot;date&quot; id=&quot;dataInit__id__&quot; class=&quot;form-control&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot;&gt; &lt;/th&gt; &lt;th class=&quot;col-sm-2&quot;&gt; &lt;input type=&quot;date&quot; id=&quot;dataFin__id__&quot; class=&quot;form-control&quot;runat=&quot;server&quot;&gt; &lt;/th&gt; &lt;th class=&quot;col-sm-2&quot;&gt; &lt;select id=&quot;opcion__id__&quot; runat=&quot;server&quot; class=&quot;formularioChekLst form-control&quot;&gt; &lt;/option&gt; &lt;option&gt;Opci&#243;n">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th></th>
      <th>SKU</th>
      <th>Precio €</th>
      <th>Descripción</th>
      <th>Fecha Inicio Demo</th>
      <th>Fecha Fin Demo</th>
      <th>Tipo de préstamo</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Then the javascript which keeps generating the rows

```
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript">
           var table = $('#tablaSKU');

           rowCount = 1;

           function appendRow() {
               var content = table.data('row-prototype').replace(/__id__/g, rowCount);

               table.find('tbody').append(content);

               ++rowCount;
               document.getElementById('rowCounter').value = rowCount - 1;
           }

           $(function () {
               appendRow(); // Append the first row on page load

               $('div#myform').on('change', function () {
                   var inputs = $(this).find(':input,select'),
        valid = true;
                   $.each(inputs, function () {
                       if ($(this).val() == '') {
                           valid = false;
                       }
                   });

                   if ((valid) && rowCount < 11) {
                       appendRow();

                   }
                   if ((valid) && rowCount >= 11) {
                       window.alert("Ha alcanzado el número máximo de SKUs(10)");
                   }
               });
           });
</script>
```

The problem is that if I'd try to access the input for example SKU from the row 5 (that will be named by the script with id sku5) it will say from the code behind that the sku5.Text will not exist.

Thank you

Comment: what is the flow of your code and what you are trying to achieve is unclear

Comment: You also need to add your code behind logic.  What is causing your postback to the server?  Honestly if you can I would suggest moving to MVC framework.  There are plenty of free video's and it works SO MUCH better with a well developed front end like you seem to be using.

Comment: @Patel I have a script that automatically creates rows, each row has an input of the type input1, input2....


I want to access to the input1, input2, but the code behind won't recognize those elements inputX as they aren't always present.

What I wanted to know if there is something to do such as if inputX exists, then take its value, else ignore.

For example if I want to access the input from the 5th column I would do something like input5.Text, but the code behind won't recognize it as its not specifically declared, its something it will apear when the javascript executes if it ever does.